# Missing code snippet "testc" after R# install

Tags: .net, visual-studio, testing, resharper, code-snippets

After installing R#8 on my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, I lost "testc" snippet. Rest of code snippets work fine, but this one in unrecognized. How can I turn it on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't show Visual Studio snippets in code completion, but they're still there. Type `testc` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>. It should expand the snippet.